# Multiple images inside one container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So, here is the problem, I **need to do** some **development** and for that I need following packages:

1. MongoDb
2. NodeJs
3. Nginx
4. RabbitMq
5. Redis

One option is that **I take a Ubuntu image**, **create a container** and start installing them one by one and done, start my server, and expose the ports.

But this can easily be done in a virtual box also, and it will not going to use the power of Docker. So for that I have to start building my own image with these packages. Now here is the question if I start writing my Dockerfile and if place the commands to download the Node js (and others) inside of it, this again becomes the same thing like virtualization.

What I need is that I **start from Ubuntu** and keep on **adding** the **references** of **MongoDb, NodeJs, RabbitMq, Nginx and Redis** inside the **Dockerfile** and finally expose the respective ports out.

Here are the queries I have:

1. Is this possible? Like adding the refrences of other images inside the Dockerfile when you are starting FROM one base image.
2. If yes then how?
3. Also is this the correct practice or not?
4. How to do these kind of things in Docker ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would use docker-compose to take single service images and create a set of containers. The compose file will define how this group of images will connect with each other and with the outside world.

Comment: Thanks @tillaert will; look in to it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Keep images light. Run one service per container. Use the official images on docker hub for mongodb, nodejs, rabbitmq, nginx etc. Extend them if needed. If you want to run everything in a fat container you might as well just use a VM.

You can of course do crazy stuff in a dev setup, but why spend time setting up something that has **zero** value in a production environment? What if you need to scale up one of the services? How do set memory and cpu constraints on each service? .. and the list goes on.

Don't make monolithic containers.

A good start is to use docker-compose to configure a set of services that can talk to each other. You can make a prod and dev version of your `docker-compose.yml` file.

**Getting into the right frame of mind**

In a perfect world you would run your containers in clustered environment in production to be able to scale your system and have concurrency, but that might be overkill depending on what you are running. It's at least good to have this in the back of your head because it can help you to make the right decisions.

Some points to think about if you want to be a purist :

- How do you have persistent volume storage across multiple hosts?
- Reverse proxy / load balancer should probably be the entry point into the system that talks to the containers using the internal network.
- Is my service even able run in a clustered environment (multiple instances of the container)

You can of course do dirty things in dev such as mapping in host volumes for persistent storage (and many people who use docker standalone in prod do that as well).

Ideally we should separate docker in dev and docker i prod. Docker is a fantastic tool during development as you can have redis, memcached, postgres, mongodb, rabbitmq, node or whatnot up and running in minutes sharing that compose setup with the rest of the team. Docker in prod can be a completely different beast.

I would also like to add that I'm generally against the fanaticism that "everything should be running in docker" in prod. Run services in docker when it makes sense. It's also not uncommon for larger companies to make their own base images. This can be a lot of work and will require maintenance to keep up with security fixes etc. It's not necessarily the first thing you jump on when starting with docker.

Comment: Perfect Point. So the best practice is to start every package in its own container and let them talk to each other. And how does I share this setup with some one else or deploy it in production setup?

Comment: You can start by using docker-compose. Describes everything in a yml file.

Comment: I've extended my answer a lot. That could possibly help you get into the right frame of mind.

Comment: Thanks man, now I need to read about how to stitch my whole development stack, and make it work around docker. Pretty complex it would be. Thanks again.

Comment: "Why spend time on something that has zero production value?"

That's amusing to read for anyone who has wasted several hours on a docker-compose to find out how painful it is to use on ECS.