# Run 3 Docker images together as a single service

Tags: docker, nginx, ffmpeg, dockerfile, http-live-streaming

I want to run 3 Docker images as a single service. They are the official `nginx`, `jrottenberg/ffmpeg` and a custom image.

The custom image will return video files for HTTP requests on port 80, e.g. `http://<container_ip>/<some_id>/video.mp4`.

I want to make the video files available for HLS in M3U8 playlist (or other better formats?).

The main idea is as follows:

- Encode `video.mp4`, output `video.m3u8` and segment files with ffmpeg
- Serve the `video.m3u8` and segment files with Nginx
- The final and the only available web service of the container is `http://<container_ip>/<some_id>.m3u8`.
- Encode only when someone is requesting it (i.e. trigger the encoding when the first request comes, stop encoding and delete segment files when nobody requests it)

I tested the HLS part with ffmpeg and it works. I am just not sure about how to put Nginx and ffmpeg to work together.

Comment: Have you looked at docker-compose?

Comment: Is it possible to make these work in a single container?

Comment: Is there a reason that you need everything inside one container instead of using multiple containers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229777/multiple-images-inside-one-container