# Combining Unit Tests from Multiple Projects into One Docker Image for Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I have followed the following article on getting my unit tests working in a Docker image and publishing via Azure DevOps pipeline.

[Running Your Unit Tests With Visual Studio Team Services and Docker Compose](https://medium.com/@christiansparre/running-your-unit-tests-with-visual-studio-team-services-and-docker-compose-3f82c9b95bf)

Each one of my unit tests projects have a very basic Dockerfile:

First Dockerfile for Application Tests

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/Application.Tests
RUN dotnet restore
```

Second DockerFile for Infrastructure tests.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/Infrastructure.Tests
RUN dotnet restore
```

My docker-compose for both images:

```
application.tests:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}applicationtests
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Application.Tests/Dockerfile
    entrypoint: > 
        dotnet test --results-directory /testresults --logger trx 
        /p:CollectCoverage=true 
        /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura 
        /p:CoverletOutput=/testresults/Application.Tests.cobertura.xml
        /p:Exclude="[xunit.*]"
    volumes:
        - /opt/vsts/work/_temp:/testresults

infrastructure.tests:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}infrastructuretests
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Infrastructure.Tests/Dockerfile
    entrypoint: > 
        dotnet test --results-directory /testresults --logger trx 
        /p:CollectCoverage=true 
        /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura 
        /p:CoverletOutput=/testresults/Infrastructure.Tests.cobertura.xml
        /p:Exclude="[xunit.*]"
    volumes:
        - /opt/vsts/work/_temp:/testresults
```

Is there a way to combine the definition for each image in docker-compose?  I understand that I can combine the tests into a single project, but want to maintain a 1:1 relationship between project and test project.

I should also add that both projects are in the same solution (.NET Core).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to run the tests for all projects in a single
>   azure-pipeline task?

It's not available with DockerCompose task. According to your scenario, you should avoid combining multiple containers into one image. As the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229777/multiple-images-inside-one-container) pointed that images should be kept light, and run one service per container.

[Docker Compose Task](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is just the way to manage these services with multiple containers to run in your application. .

> Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications. With Compose, you use a YAML file to configure your application’s services. Then, with a single command, you create and start all the services from your configuration

If you insist on combing everything together, Docker compose is not fit for your case.

You could have a try with [multiple stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) dockerfile to combine these dockerfiles into one. This will end up with a single image when your run docker build

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  You confirmed my thoughts.  I removed the second part of my question about azure-pipelines, and marked this as the answer to the Docker question.